# insert function call depending on parameters

Tags: c

I have found no way of inserting a function call depending on previously included variables:

I would like the user call this function

```
char *call_the_microprocessor_function_with_parameters(char *port, char *pin);
// internally it will concatenate "DDR"+"port"+"pin"

char *result = call_the_microprocessor_function_with_parameters("B", "5");
// will result in "DDRB5"
```

but how can I then add the call DDRB5 to the code?

```
// so it results in 
DDRB5 = HIGH;
```

to elaborate: imagine I need to set pin 5 of port B high to toggle an LED, I would call:

```
    #include <microprocessor_library.h>
    char *result = call_the_microprocessor_function_with_parameters("B", "5");
    TheMagicFunctionJustWritesTheNameOfFunction(result) = HIGH;
    //equivalent to
    DDRBB5 = HIGH
    // this would be the call to the actual microprocessor library
```

I tried with #define, but that resulted in a lot of issues
and if I want to use function pointers and strcmp's, with four ports each having 8 pins, it would result in 32 switch statements

is this an example of reflection (which is not possible in pure c)?

Comment: [DDRB5](https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/blob/master/avr-libc/include/avr/iom8a.h#L225) is just 5 .. You can't to `DDRB5 = HIGH`. You have to implement all the abstraction.

Comment: You may want a `cpp` macro: `#define PORTNAME(port_,pin_) *DDR##port_##pin_` and then do: `PORTNAME(B,5) = HIGH;` Beyond that you probably want to generate a table of all port addresses, etc. to eliminate the `switch`. Or, just `*DDRB5 = HIGH;` It's unclear what you're really asking for.

Comment: but is I write DDRB5 straight into the code, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C is compiled and cant modify its own code.

You have three options:

use OO language. Create objects and you will have this level of abstraction. How you will tag the objects it language and programmer dependent.

---

Write the C program which will emit the new C code, build the executable. Run the new program. You can repeat those steps ad infinitum.

---

Choose the interpreted language which can modify itself -